# Unity AR Foundation(iOS) : How to using body tracking in front camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

I want to use body tracking on the front camera, not the rear camera on iOS, as in the example below.

But, body tracking always runs only on the rear camera.

How can I use body tracking without face tracking in the front camera?

[body tracking example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CdC3ZgppSp0&list=PLQMQNmwN3FvzLN-8moCKmZb00gr7sdcrZ&index=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we are also doing body tracking of ARkit3 right now, unfortunately it's not possible to track body skeleton with the front camera. But I believe in the future, Apple will do some improvement to achieve that. I've given them feedback about this. Let's wait and see.

Comment: any update that you know of since then? it's been over a year